# SQL Server 2000 to 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, restore

When I try to restore a database abackup from a SQL Server 2000 to 2008 R2m, I get this error:

[image]

Actually, I don't quite get it. What does the error actually mean?

And how can I solve it?

Answer (score 9):

Your database has multiple filegroups. You can't just use the simple UI dialog to say "restore database"... you need to use `WITH MOVE` to indicate which files should go where (even if they all are going to end up in the same location). We can't really tell you what your actual `RESTORE` command will look like without seeing the results of:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\<path>\<file>.bak';
```

This will tell you the names and paths of the filenames within the backup. Once you know what they are, you can writ a command like:

```
RESTORE DATABASE whatever FROM DISK = 'C:\<path>\<file>.bak'
  WITH MOVE 'file1' TO 'D:\<path>\file1.mdf',
       MOVE 'file2' TO 'D:\<path>\file2.mdf,
       ...etc etc...;
```

I strongly recommend you become familiar with the [`BACKUP DATABASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) and [`RESTORE DATABASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) commands, and do this in a query window instead of using the UI. The UI is fine for some of the simple stuff, but it's not so good at more complex scenarios, and those are probably the ones you don't want it screwing up.

(It may also be the case that this is only a partial filegroup backup.)

Comment: thank you for your answer...but I found out a very simple way to solve it............after considering your answer.

Comment: @user883434: it would be nice if you would **share** the solution you found with us!

Comment: Especially since you unaccepted my answer after you found your "simple" solution.